# Allowing Password to be any length Crypto

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I have found the following code to encrypt an excel file in python. However, I noticed that it is only able to use passwords/key of length 16 or 32 characters in order to encrypt the file. I would like the user to be able to use any length passwords from 8 - 32 characters to encrypt the file. I was thinking that maybe the user could put in a password with 8 characters, and then I could add in some filler characters to get it to a length of 16. However, this does not seem like an idea that is used.

Hence I was wondering how else could I create a key of different length to encrypt the file?

```
def pad(s):
    return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
    message = pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

def encrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()
    enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
    with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)

def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
    with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)

encryptPassword = "some 16 or 32 character password"
key = encryptPassword.encode("utf8")
encrypt_file(excelSheet, key)
```

Comment: You appear to have conflated the concepts of **key** and **password**. They're two different things. You can use a password to generate a key by passing it through a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). This will turn a password of any length into a fixed-length key that you can use for encrypting and decrypting. The process of turning a password into a key should also be relatively [time-consuming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), to make brute-force attacks harder.